# How do I find out who manufactured the plumbing in my home?

Tags: plumbing

There is a nationwide class action lawsuit going on against defective manufactured copper piping in homes. I need to find out who manufactured my home's copper piping to determine if my piping qualifies under the lawsuit. What resources should I investigate to determine the said information? I do have a home that is a part of a planned community, a.k.a. a "cookie-cutter" home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would physically examine the pipe to find markings printed during the manufacture, which are usually printed in blue or black and identify the size, grade, and sometimes the manufacturer and batch.